# Bourne Shell to CShell

Tags: shell-script, csh, bourne-shell

This works fine:

```
#!/bin/sh

ALTER="$1"
NAME="$2"

for pr in $(pgrep $NAME); do
    elapse=$(ps -o etime= -p $pr)
    [ "${elapse%:*}" -gt "$ALTER" ] && echo $pr
done
```

But if I try to switch it to CShell:

```
#!/bin/csh

set ALTER = "$1"
set NAME = "$2"

for pr in $(pgrep $NAME); do
    set elapse = $(ps -o etime= -p $pr)
    [ "${elapse%:*}" -gt "$ALTER" ] && echo $pr
done
```

I get an `Illegal variable` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you like to convert something to csh at all? csh is not really useful for scripting.

Comment: somebody told me to do it :/

Comment: @JuM then they really, really hate you. Trying to script in `csh` is just painful and should be avoided at all costs really.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for all the replies! :)

Comment: IMO csh should be avoided even as a CLI shell because you've got all the usual csh problems for your one-liners, AND you have to use a different language (e.g. sh or bash or ksh etc) for your scripts.  As a CLI shell, there's nothing csh can do that bash, zsh, or a modern ksh can't do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you should know about scripting in `csh` is that it is [usually a very bad idea](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). That said, if you insist, the problems with your script are:

- `csh` doesn't support the `$()` construct for command substitution, use `` ` ` `` instead.
- `csh` doesn't support the `for i ... do ... done` syntax, use `foreach i ... end` instead.
- `csh` doesn't do funky string manipulation like `"${elapse%:*}"`. You'll have to get around it using some other tool.
- I don't know how to get `[` to work with `csh` (but it's probably possible), as a workaround, use `if` instead.

So, a working version of your script in `csh` would be:

```
#!/bin/csh
set ALTER = "$1" 
set NAME = "$2" 
foreach pr  (`pgrep "$NAME"`)
    set elapse = `ps -o etime= -p "$pr" | cut -d: -f1` 
    if ( "$elapse" > "$ALTER" ) echo "$pr"
end
```

Seriously though, don't script in `csh`, it will only cause you pain. Especially since all you really need is:

```
 ps -o pid=,etime= -p $(pgrep $NAME) | cut -d: -f1 | 
        awk -vval="$ALTER" '$2>val{print $1}'
```

Comment: *Version: $Id: csh-faq,v 1.7 95/09/28 12:52:17 tchrist Exp Locker: tchrist $* **Happy Birthday!** Twenty years later and people are still being told to use csh.

Comment: `[` is an external command; I'd be very surprised if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Random832 it's both a builtin and an external one, but yes, good point. `/usr/bin/[ 10 > 5 ] && echo y` seems to work in csh. `[ 10 > 5 ] && echo y` doesn't. I don't know the details, I'm happy to remain ignorant of csh :)

Comment: Well, `>` isn't actually a supported operator in the `[` command; you need -gt and you need to be comparing integers. By the way, check for a file named `5` in the directory you tested it in.

Comment: @Random832 d'oh! Yup, that created `5`. However, this still fails in csh: `[ 5 -gt 4 ] && echo y`. Anyway, answer edited to reflect that csh could probably use `[` if not for my ignorance. Thanks.

Comment: Do you also got an idea how I can avoid pgrep?
I tried something like that:
foreach pr  (`grep "$NAME" | awk '{$2}'`)
but it doesn't work fine...

Comment: @JuM well no, that wouldn't work. `grep` has nothing to do with `pgrep`, it needs an input. Why would you want to avoid `pgrep`?

Answer (score 3):

`${var%$pattern}` is a POSIX-shell construct (introduced by ksh) not available in `csh`.

You could use `expr` here:

```
expr "$elapse" : '\([0-9]*\)' '>' "$ALTER" > /dev/null && echo $pr
```

But I would first

1. avoid `csh`
2. avoid `csh`
3. [avoid loops in shell scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716). Here the whole thing can be done by piping `ps` to `awk` in a syntax compatible with most shells.

Comment: You forgot to mention that he should avoid `csh` :-)